# How can I make this cost calculator script shorter?

Tags: javascript

```
function Method(Distance,Cost,Milage) {
    result1=parseInt(Distance/Cost*Milage);
    result2=parseInt(Distance/46*Cost);
    alert('Your trip will costs  '+  result1  +' $');
    alert('Your trip in hybrid costs  '+    result2   +' $');
    if ((result1-result2)<0)
        alert('You will save '+(result2-result1)+' $');
    else
        alert('You will save  '+(result1-result2)+' $');
    }
}
```

What can I do to make this shorter?

Comment: Short isn't always better.  I would like to suggest the method name be improved to indicate the purpose.  Also, separate your 'UI' calls from the methods that do calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
alert("You will save "+Math.abs(result1-result2)+" $");
```

This will always output the "gap" as a positive number.

As an aside, `parseInt` is redundant since you are already casting to numbers with the `/` and `*` operators.

Answer (score 1):

yes and no, at least you can write shorter :

instead off calling

```
Method(Distance,Cost,Milage);
```

everytime.

you could just alert

```
alert("You will save "+Math.abs((Distance/Cost*Milage)-(Distance/46*Cost)+" $");
```

everytime

Comment: I love long complicated lines.

Comment: @bjb568 i added an extra long complicated line for you ;-D

Comment: What's that update about? Oh.